# What program can I use to create and edit json files?

Tags: json, macos

I'm using osx and want to create and edit json files. Is there a program that I can use to do this automatically?

For example I have an excel file that I want to convert into JSON format. I thought I could read in the file using python and write it out according to the json schema, but I was not sure if there was an easier way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to convert an Excel document to JSON you can use something like: http://tamlyn.org/tools/csv2json/

If you're just looking to manipulate JSON data visually you can use something like: http://braincast.nl/samples/jsoneditor/

Answer (score 0):

If your want to edit or create json file, you can use this tool http://codedestine.com/json-editor.html .It has feature to add date and its drag and drop UI makes it easy to construct json.

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless 
if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site 
just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy 
the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing 
your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always 
leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your 
material...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will prepare this answer with few screenshot on to how to use it and update this answer.